# PHP - Date based on the number of the day minus 2 - N

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have the a day of the week saved as a **number** N for the customer in the database. e.g. Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2 etc.

I would like to have a statement that can tell if it's 2 days before that day.

For instance if…

customer day = 0 and today is 5 = true

customer day = 5 and today is 3 = true

customer day = 1 and today is 6 = true

Comment: are you sure that both 0 and 7 are possible?

Comment: I would suggest using arrays. You've flexible way of circling the data in there.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(($today+2)%7 == $customer)//ok
```